# CloudFormation error for substitution values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Helo,
I am trying to add a trigger to a lambda function as follows. But it is throwing error as follows

```
 undefined method `match' for {"Ref"=>"EventRuleName"}
```

I have already defined a lambda and event rule prior to the creating the permissions stack .
But while running the permission stack it errored out

cloudformation

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: ""

Parameters:
  LambdaFunctionName:
    Type: String
    Default: lambda-function1
  EventBridgeRuleRoleName:
    Type: String
    Default: EventBridgeRuleRole1
  EventRuleName:
    Type: String
    Default: EventBridgeRule1
  Env:
    Type: String
  AWSTenant:
    Type: String
  TeamTag:
    Type: String
    Default: team1

Resources:
  PermissionForEvent0ToInvokeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunctionName
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - !Ref EventRuleName
          - "Arn"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fetch the Arn from the `EventRuleName` because that is a string parameter.

It would work if the EventRule is deployed in the same stack. Then you can use `!Ref` and fetch the Arn of the EventRule.

If you need to separate the stacks, I would

- Pass in the EventRule Arn into the stack instead of the EventRule Name, or
- You could construct the ARN from the name

```
  PermissionForEvent0ToInvokeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunctionName
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn:
        Fn::Sub:
          - arn:aws:events:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:rule/${EventRuleName}
```